# DB Update and Redirect (CakePHP)

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm adding a new column to my MySQL table in a controller in CakePHP. I then redirect to a page which displays the information contained in every column in the table. However, I'm receiving an undefined index error on the new column when redirected. Upon refreshing, the page recognizes the column properly.

I'm using the following code to retrieve column names from the table:
SHOW COLUMNS IN entries

My "index" controller executes this query, sends the column names to the view, and the data is drawn there as normal.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I think the issue you are hitting is the model caching. Cake is not immediately recognizing the change in the entity's table and is not trying to load the new field on the first query. Try turning on the debugging to see if the query on the redirect contains the new field.

Comment: Thank you very much Erik. After adding "$this->Model->save()" the data seems to have flushed properly. Cheers :)